# Как правильно настроить Security Config, а именно запросы, не требующие авторизации?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, postman

Тестирую приложение через постман - никак не могу откл аутентификацию в конфиге -

@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/post/**","/api/auth/register")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().and()
        .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .permitAll();

}

запрос register возвращает страницу логирования [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что делаю не так? подскажите плиз

Comment: Замените картинку с кодом текстом

Comment: Не нужно писать длинный код в комментарии. Отредактируйте сам вопрос.